# Gif appear when click Ctrl key

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to make a shooting gif appear when click in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key in JavaScript ?

Thanks

I only have the click event:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
if(event.keyCode == 17) {
document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "Ctrl - Shoot";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe possible, if your or your client's browser supports gif rendering.

Why not just put a image?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
  if(event.keyCode == 17) {
    document.getElementById("key").innerHTML = "<img src=\"shooting.gif\">";
  }
});
```

You should also set `width`, `height` and `alt` properties to `img` tag.